# ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Need a little help here, think I have tried everything to fix this issue but keep getting the same error message `ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

**CODE**:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="xx", passwd="", database="xx")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO authors(id, first_name, last_name, photo) VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s)"
values = ['''(1,'Herbert','Methley','NULL'),
(2,'Olive','Wellwood','NULL'),
(3,'Francis','Tugwell ','NULL'),(4,'Randolph','Henry Ash','NULL'),
(5,'Christabel','LaMotte ','NULL'),(7,'Robert','Dale Owen','NULL'),
(12,'Leonora','Stern ','NULL'),(14,'Mrs.','Lees ','NULL'),(19'Josephine','M. Bettany','NULL'),
(20,'Kester','Bellever ','NULL'),(22,'Sylvia','Leigh ','NULL'),(24,'Elizabeth','Temple ','NULL'),
(25,'Marsha','Patterson ','NULL'),(26,'Samuel','Humber ','NULL'),(27,'James','Fallon ','NULL'),
(28,'Beatrice','Quinn ','NULL'),(29,'Susan','Magar ','NULL'),(30,'Clinton','York ','NULL'),
(31,'Canton','Lee ','NULL'),(32,'Rod','Keen ','NULL'),(33,'Hilda','Simpson ','NULL'),
(34,'S.','M. Justice','NULL'),(35,'Charles','Green ','NULL'),(36,'Richard','Brautigan ','NULL'),
(37,'Bill','Lewis ','NULL'),(38,'Chuck',' ','NULL'),(39,'Doctor','O. ','NULL'),
(40,'Harlow','Blade ','NULL'),(41,'Barbara','Jones ','NULL'),(42,'Fred','Sinkus ','NULL'),
(43,'Thomas','Funnel ','NULL'),(44,'Patricia','Evens Summers','NULL'),
(45,'Reverend','Lincoln Lincoln','NULL'),(47,'Edward','Fox ','NULL')''']

mycursor.executemany(sql, values)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted")
```

**ERROR  MESSAGE**:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts\PYTHONMYSQL_TEST.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       mycursor.executemany(sql, values)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
>   line 668, in executemany
>       stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
>   line 614, in _batch_insert
>       "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
>
> ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Any help would be appreciated, I believe I have given everyone all the information needed.  If I have forgot something please let me know

thanks

Comment: Your values are a list of a single string (enclosed by `'''`), not a list of tuples. Try removing the `'''`

Comment: Also note that `'NULL'` is a _string_, not actual `NULL`.  Remove the single quotes.

Comment: And you're not populating the photo column at all so just leave it out of your insert column list and the associated rows.

Comment: OK, thanks I will give this a try and get back to you!

Comment: OK this worked but had to remove NULL from values in order for it to work!  Thanks for you help!